# Can miners be paid transaction fees even if they don't solve the current block?

Tags: transaction-fees, litecoin, solo-mining

I was recently mining on ltc.tbdice site which is a solo type site. They only pay out when a block is found and nearly all goes straight to the miner.

I had set up a specific wallet address for this mining pool and I recently had a very small payment show up in there even though I have never gotten a block on that site.

It was about 0.00065 LTC (sorry, don't have wallet with me right now).

So is this a correct payment or maybe just a bug on that specific website? It doesn't really make sense to me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the point of a mining pool is that everyone gets a portion of the mining profit (in proportion to how much hash power they contribute relative to everyone else) regardless of whether their own miner found the correct block or not.

This is so that small miners can make a more consistent and predictable revenue. If they mined by themselves, their chance of finding a block is very low, resulting in an unpredictable revenue stream where the vast majority of the time they would make no revenue.

Comment: Thank you kaykurokawa but your answer absolutely did not answer the question. I am very familiar with regular pools and how they pay out, I mine LTC, BTC and CANN in pools. The "pool" I am talking about says that they only pay out when a person hits a block, the miner gets 99.5% of they block and they take 0.5% as a fee. So I would like to know if what I asked in the title is possible: can a miner be paid for transactions even if they don't mine the current block (and the coin still has blocks left to mine). I also forgot to add that my wallet shows the mining symbol and says the 0.00066849 am